# How to read the actual value of @P0 in SQL server profiler

Tags: sql-server, profiler

When I use SQL server profiler to trace the SQL statement flow using `SP:StmtCompleted`,

I can only read the variables as `@P0, @P1`, etc. like:

```
insert into CaseFollowup (createDate, duration) values (@P0, @P1)
```

Can I read the actual value of @P0, @P1?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use rpc_completed to get parameter values. Also, use extended events instead of profiler if you're on SQL 2012 or newer.